# Predicate matching a list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to do something like -

```
List<int> accountList = new List<int>();
accountList .Add(1);
accountList .Add(27);


var rec = _db.Accounts.Where(a=> accountList.Contains(a.accountId)).Take(10);
```

My code is a little more complicated than this - there are several other conditions in the where clause, but this is the bit that is causing problems - nothing gets returned even when there are matching values.

Basically I want it to retrieve all the records where accountId matches a value in my list.

Any pointers?

> The sample above is giving me a cant convert lambda error.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - that doesn't look like it should even compile, due to the argument to `Contains`.

Comment: Are `accounts` vs. `accountList` really different? You're missing a parenthesis. Unrelated: make accountList a set if you can.

Comment: Where(a=> , Contains(a=>, will make any IDE kick you with double declaration with the same name

Comment: Apologies for the errors - now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a bit on your contains version

```
 var hold2 = _db.Accounts.Where(a => find.Contains(a.accountDd)).Take(10).ToList();
```

Have you tried using any

```
 var hold2 = _db.Accounts.Where(a => accountList.Any(m => m == a.accountId)).Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: Still getting nothing back using .Any

Comment: Check the count on your _db.Accounts i tested it and it was working

Comment: PICNIC.  Sorted.